# MS Access Reserved Error (-1517) when updating a back-end SharePoint list

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, limit, reserved

I am using Office365/Access 2016 as a front-end, with an on-premises SharePoint 2013 list as a back-end.

The users need to leave notes for each other in the list, which should also retain a history of those notes.

I am using one multiline/Long Text field, called "latest_note", to enter the new note, which is then appended via an update query to another field, "notes", which is then the historical record of notes.

The process, effectively, adds the whole content of "notes" to the "latest_note", erases the "notes" field, and then UPDATEs it with the "latest_note" + "notes".

This works very nicely until the "latest_note" + "notes" hits around 2000 (2K/maybe 2048?) characters.  At that moment, it raises the following error:

---

Run-time error '3000':

### Reserved error (-1517); there is no message for this error.

Of course, then you have to force-close the app etc.

I did some limited testing and think that this is caused by Access not being able to add a text of 2K size to the field it's updating.

I do have some alternative workarounds for this issue, but am just curious to hear if anyone else has run into this specific error or limitation?  I wasn't able to find a single reference googling it.

Comment: Check and see if it is long text for certain and if there is a character limit on it. You can set a short text field to take 1-4k characters. Long text goes to 2^30-1 bytes though. Both types allow you to set a limit on the number of characters though.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  Both fields are set to Multi Line in SharePoint, with 1000 lines each (the maximum allowed) and appear as Long Text within Access.

Comment: And you confirmed that there isn't a limit set on access? It can be long text without a limit?

Comment: The long text field(s) are all as read from the SharePoint backend.  I created the Access frontend and I am not aware that I implemented any limits on any of the fields (and did double-check, just in case).  The only difference between the two fields that I can actually see is that the "last_note" fields is "Append Only -- No" and the "notes" field (into which the individual "last_note"s get appended) is set to "Append Only -- Yes".

Comment: Not sure what you are running into. I was hoping someone else would jump in but it doesn't seem like it. Did you solve it? If so, add the answer yourself and mark it correct. If not... I was trying to find an answer for you and came across a list of why long-text might get truncated. It isn't exactly what you have going on, but take a look and see if there is a setting or comment that might be loosely related to the issue. http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, Rodger.  Good old Allen, too bad he's no longer Access-ible :^).

I am still investigating.  The ideas under the link might point to something, but it could also be an issue related to the backend SharePoint list.  I will definitely post once I find an answer/solution or if I've decided to go down a different path.